# Google: always I am the first result on second page

Tags: google-search

I am searching on Google my published articles but I don't understand why I am always the first result on the second page? (My site is also, on Google news and it appears as news on first page, but the article is first, on the second page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about this matter because your (published article’s) ranking on Google is based on the quality of Article (User Lovable) and other SEO work (Not only based on the SEO work but also based on the relevancy of user searched keyword). So get some quality back links to your article page and share your article on Social Media sites then your article page will improve on Google Ranking. Please don’t over optimize which will surely affect your page's ranking on Google. So don’t think that your page has been ranking on the first position of Second page because some sites would rank on same position for more days.

Ranking on Google Web Search and News are entirely different so don’t confuse by combining both.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! @SathiyaKumar I have Googled my article name as it appear on Google. No one other website has the same title as me, but i still the first on second page... I have checked from other networks, PCs and the problem is the same. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome ITChristian! If you need more help give me the Title of your Article and your URL. I will analyze and tell you more tips to improve the ranking.